# E pluribus unum or Ex pluribus unum?

Tags: preposition, spelling

I've seen the phrase in both wordings *E pluribus unum* and *Ex pluribus unum*. Which one is correct?

See [my follow-up question](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/5028/79) for the double meaning of this phrase.

Comment: Related: [Why “ex nihilo” instead of “e nihilo”?](https://latin.stackexchange.com/q/2430/12)

Comment: Also related: [How to say, “Many are not one?”](https://latin.stackexchange.com/questions/2831/how-to-say-many-are-not-one-pluribus-non-paribus-unum/2835#2835)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Both ex and e are correct before consonants, with ex more common (confirmed by Lewis and Short), while ex is of course required before vowels. In his *Confessions*, St Augustine wrote (IV.8) "flagrare animos et ex pluribus unum facere". As a motto of the USA, I believe it is always "e pluribus unum".

Comment: Google's ngram viewer appears to disagree (at least in regards to usage post 1800)

Comment: @Strawberry That would be greatly biased by it being the motto of the USA, though.

Comment: @Graipher Yes - but zero hits?

Comment: @Strawberry Ah, I did not actually check how large the difference was...

Comment: @Graipher But you're probably correct in a way. I suspect that prior to its adoption as the US motto (1782), both spellings were used.

Comment: A 1923 article in The Classical Journal gives the first proven use of the phrase "e pluribus unum" as 1692 and suggests it is an adaptation of a slightly different phrase - de pluribus una - in Horace. [link](http://penelope.uchicago.edu/Thayer/E/Journals/CJ/18/7/E_Pluribus_Unum*.html) As stated in another answer, in classical Latin ex pluribus seems to be much more common than e pluribus, though both are good Latin.

Answer (score 8):

The general rule for the use of *e* and *ex* as prepositions can be found in Latin grammars like Gildersleeve's:

> **Ē** is used before consonants only, **ex** before both vowels and consonants. ([§417.6](https://books.google.com/books?id=UU0BIAbE0SIC&pg=PA272))

Lewis and Short write that *ex* is still more common than *e* in front of consonants, but that some forms tend to use *e*:

> **ex** or *ē* (*ex* always before vowels, and elsewh. more freq. than *e*; e. g. in Cic. Rep. *e* occurs 19 times, but *ex* 61 times, before consonants—but no rule can be given for the usage; cf., e. g., *ex* and *e* together: qui ex corporum vinculis tamquam e carcere evolaverunt, *Cic. Rep. 6, 14*. But certain expressions have almost constantly the same form, as ex parte, ex sententia, ex senatus consulto, ex lege, ex tempore, etc.; but e regione, e re nata, e vestigio, e medio, and e republica used adverbially. ([source](http://perseus.uchicago.edu/cgi-bin/philologic/getobject.pl?c.4:1497.lewisandshort))

With respect to the word *pluribus*, PHI's concordance of Classical Latin gives [108 instances of *ex* preceding it](http://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23ex+pluribus), and [only five of *e*](http://latin.packhum.org/concordance?q=%23e+pluribus).  One of the latter reads as follows:

> paulatim singula uires deperdunt proprias, color est e pluribus unus, nec totus uiridis, quia lactea frusta repugnant, nec de lacte nitens, quia tot uariatur ab herbis. ([Appendix Vergiliana, *Moretum* 1, 101–4](http://latin.packhum.org/loc/692/11/0/4642-4652#0))

So both are correct, and in Classical Latin at least, *ex* is more common.